# TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function at ReactLoadablePlugin.apply

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-cli

I want to implement SSR in ReactJs using React Loadable by Webpack. Below are a few lines from the package.json file:

```
const { ReactLoadablePlugin } = require('react-loadable/webpack');
plugins:[
    new ReactLoadablePlugin({
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'react-loadable.json')
    }),
]
```

But I am getting below error:

```
> [webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function
at ReactLoadablePlugin.apply
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you offer a bit more code to help readers understand how this error might have been caused?

Comment: Have you npm install the ReactLoadablePlugin package?

Comment: I recently upgraded webpack from v4 to v5 and I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?
Please provide solution if yes.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same error but with **webpack-shell-plugin**
dependency in **NodeJs** using **Webpack 5** so my fix was to remove *webpack-shell-plugin* and add **webpack-shell-plugin-next**:

`npm install --save-dev webpack-shell-plugin-next`

**webpack.config.js** file:

```
const WebpackShellPluginNext = require('webpack-shell-plugin-next');

module.exports = {
 ...
plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPluginNext({
      onBuildStart:{
        scripts: ['echo "===> Starting packing with WEBPACK 5"'],
        blocking: true,
        parallel: false
      },
      onBuildEnd:{
        scripts: ['npm run yourCommand'],
        blocking: false,
        parallel: true
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

I hope this fix can help you or can help someone.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is likely that you try to use a Webpack 4 plugin with Webpack 5, just Webpack has uninformative error messages. Try to upgrade the ReactLoadablePlugin.

Comment: mine is already latest versoin 5.5.0, I am facing same issue. "webpack": "^5.75.0" & "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"